# Using multiple custom meta data keyword Criteria in a single query as LIKE operators

Tags: broker, metadata, query

I need to accomplish the following, and I can't find any working method for it.

We have articles with a custom metadata field of comma-separated keyword values, the code I've built split's by comma and then creates Criteria for each eg:

```
CustomMetaKeyCriteria metaField = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("articleKeywords");

for(int i=0; i < keywords.length; i++){
  keywordCriterias[i] = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(metaField, keywords[k], FieldOperator.LIKE);
}
```

I then want to search against the other article's keywords, using the LIKE operator so it'll search for each keyword within its keyword metadata.

I've been unable to combine the Criteria into a single one though, could someone talk me through how to do this? Every approach I've tried has failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

@Kris, I am assuming you have custom meta value as a comma separated string. You can use SQL like pattern %% to match the value. So your custom meta value criteria should be like:

```
CustomMetaValueCriteria customMetaValueCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(metaField, "%keywordValue%", Criteria.Like);
```

You can fit this code in your application code.